# Networkx (or Graphviz) layout with fixed y positions

Tags: layout, networkx, graphviz, directed-acyclic-graphs

Are there any layout algorithms in networkx (or that I can call in Graphviz) that allow me to fix the Y-position of nodes in a DAG to a potentially different floating point value for each node, but spread out the X positions in some reasonable way (ideally attempting to minimise edge lengths or crossovers, although I suspect this might not be possible)? I can only find layouts that require nodes to be on discrete layers.

Added: Below is an example of the sort of graph topology I have, plotted using `nx.kamada_kawai_layout`. The thing is that these nodes have a "time" value (not shown here), which I want to plot on the Y axis. The vertices are directed in time, so that a parent node (e.g. 54 here) is always older than its children (here 52 and 53). So I want to lay this out with the Y position given by the node "time", and the X position such that crossings are minimised, in as much as that's possible (I know this is NP hard in general, but the layout below is actually doing a pretty good job. [image: graph plot]

p.s. usually all the leaf nodes, e.g. 2, 3, 7 here, are at time 0, so should be laid out at the bottom of the final layout.

p.p.s. Essentially what I would like to do is to imagine this as a spring diagram, "pick up" the root node (54) in the plot above and place it at the top of the page, with the topology dangling down, then adjust the Y-position of the children to the their internal "time" values.

Edit 2. Thanks to @sroush below, I can get a decent layout with the dot graphviz engine:

```
A = nx.nx_agraph.to_agraph(G)
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(10, 10))
A.add_subgraph(ts.samples(), level="same", name="cluster")
A.layout(prog="dot")
pos = {n: [float(x) for x in A.get_node(n).attr["pos"].split(",")] for n in G.nodes()}
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, with_labels=True)
```

[image: standard dot layout]

But I then want to reposition the nodes slightly so instead of ranked times (the numbers) they use their actual, floating point times. Like this:

```
true_times = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'time')
reposition = {node_id: np.array([pos[node_id][0], true_times[node_id]]) for node_id in true_times}
nx.draw_networkx(G, reposition, with_labels=True)
```

[image: Repositioned nodes]

As you can see, that squashed the nodes together rather a lot. Is there any way to increase the horizontal positions of those nodes to make them not bump into one-another? I could perhaps cluster some on to the same layer and iterate, but that seems quite expensive.

Comment: Can you clarify your question with some kind of visual layout?

Answer (score 1):

The Graphviz **dot** engine can get you pretty close.  This is usually described as a "timeline" issue.  Here is a graph that is part of the Graphviz source that seems to do what you want:  https://www.flickr.com/photos/kentbye/1155560169

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks. My slight issue is that my times are not integers, so nodes will not appear in binned time slices, although I could bin them arbitrarily and adjust the Y positions afterwards, I guess.

Comment: Don't know what the max/min range of Y values is, but each rank could represent less than (or more than) one unit.  Also, the intervals between ranks don't have to be linear.

Comment: I added a few more illustrations above